# C#,SQL,SQLITE Como retornar comando SQL de uma ação

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Estou com uma duvida em C# e nos comandos SQL, estou usando no momento o SQLite como banco de dados local. Em minha aplicação faço a inserção de cadastros no Banco de Dados, até aí tudo bem, mas eu queria saber se existe alguma maneira de retornar o comando que foi executado, em forma de string, por exemplo:

Este é o método de recebimento dos parametros:

```
        public void Inserir(Curso curso)
    {
        acessoaoDB.LimparParametros();
        acessoaoDB.AdicionarParametros("@NomeCurso", curso.NomeCurso);
        acessoaoDB.AdicionarParametros("@SiglaCurso", curso.SiglaCurso);
        acessoaoDB.AdicionarParametros("@Descricao", curso.Descricao);
        acessoaoDB.ExecutarManipulacao(CommandType.Text, "INSERT INTO cursos (nome_curso,sigla_curso,descricao) VALUES (@NomeCurso,@SiglaCurso,@Descricao)");
    }
```

Este é o método de inserção de dados na tabela:

```
        public void ExecutarManipulacao(CommandType commandType, string SQL)
    {
        SQLiteConnection sqlConnection = CriarConexao();
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        sqlCommand.CommandType = commandType;
        sqlCommand.CommandText = SQL;
        sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 7200;

        foreach (SQLiteParameter sqliteParameter in sqliteParameterCollection)
        {
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(sqliteParameter.ParameterName, sqliteParameter.Value));
        }

        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

O que eu queria fazer seria que após executar o comando, captura-lo da forma que foi enviado ao banco, por exemplo:

Comando com variáveis:

```
"INSERT INTO cursos (nome_curso,sigla_curso,descricao) VALUES (@NomeCurso,@SiglaCurso,@Descricao)"
```

Comando como eu queria que fosse capturado:

```
"INSERT INTO cursos (nome_curso,sigla_curso,descricao) VALUES ('Matematica','MAT123','Curso de Matematica do Ensino Medio')"
```

Muito Obrigado pela atenção de todos!

Comment: Qual o objetivo desta captura?

Comment: O objetivo é fazer um sistema de versionamento salvando diretamente as linhas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que a sua intenção seja realizar um log da query, sendo assim sugiro a seguinte implementação:

```
public string ExecutarManipulacao(CommandType commandType, string SQL)
{
    SQLiteConnection sqlConnection = CriarConexao();
    sqlConnection.Open();
    SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    sqlCommand.CommandType = commandType;
    sqlCommand.CommandText = SQL;
    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 7200;

    foreach (SQLiteParameter sqliteParameter in sqliteParameterCollection)
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(sqliteParameter.ParameterName, sqliteParameter.Value));
    }

    if (sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        return LogQuery(sqlCommand);

    return "";
}

public static string LogQuery(SQLiteCommand sqlCommand)
{
    string query = sqlCommand.CommandText;

    foreach (SQLiteParameter p in sqlCommand.Parameters)
    {
        query = query.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.ParameterValueForSQL());
    }

    return query;
}

public static string ParameterValueForSQL(this SQLiteParameter sp)
{
    string strReturn = "";

    switch (sp.DbType)
    {
        case DbType.AnsiString:
        case DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength:
        case DbType.String:
        case DbType.StringFixedLength:
            strReturn = "'" + sp.Value.ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "'";
            break;
        case DbType.Boolean:
            strReturn = Convert.ToBoolean(sp.Value) ? "1" : "0";
            break;
        default:
            strReturn = sp.Value.ToString().Replace("'", "''");
            break;
    }

    return strReturn;
}
```